# Does Midrashim exist for Neviim and Ketuvim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, tanach, midrash

I am looking for where I can find Midrashic literature on every other book of Tanakh. I own Artscroll's series of the Midrash and of course have the Megillos. If it even exists, where can I find this material?

I'll take all suggestions even if not in English.

Answer (score 5):

[Yalkut Shimoni](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalkut_Shimoni) will be the first set to look at.

Comment: Here it is on Sefaria: https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach?lang=bi (Untranslated, of course)

Comment: This is probably the only one that goes through the whole set, but the "original" midrashim are really only the ones on Samuel, Psalms, and Proverbs (Shocher Tov)

Comment: @ba Isn’t Shocher Tov on Tehillim?

Comment: @DonielF Rightly or wrongly they all bear that name (I found [an explanation](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Otzar_Midrashim,_Midrash_Shocher_Tov?lang=he) via Google if you're interested)

Comment: @ba Gotcha. Thanks, you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

A useful set would be [the Otzar Hamidrashim on Nach](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A0-%D7%9A-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%9F.html).

This English set, [The Family Midrash Says on Nach](http://www.nehora.com/the-family-midrash-says-on-nach-7-vol/), also looks intriguing.

See [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=957) (#3 lists Midrashim on Nach) as well.

Answer (score 0):

A nice set is [Otzar Agados HaNach](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/site/detail/detail/detailDetail.asp?detail_id=3907582&seaWordPage=%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA) compiled by R. Yaacov Klapholts.

Answer (score 0):

In the נחמד למראה edition of נ״ך (printed by ׳תורה מפוארה׳) includes next to the commentarys a section called מדרשי חז״ל. It brings medrashim from anywhere and everywhere that discuses the pasuk.

(ArtScroll has a similar thing in their נ״ך מקראות גדולות called ליקוטי ש״ס ומדרשי התנאים)

נחמד למראה example[image: נחמד למראה example]
Artscroll example[image: Artscroll example]